# Excel - Summing values based adjacent letter in a table array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I got a row like this:
[Current Excel Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8j4O.png)

[image]

I got a formula to sum the T and B values:

```
T: =SUM(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(C2:G2,"T","")*1,0))
B: =SUM(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(C2:G2,"B","")*1,0))
```

This works when a cell only contains values like B5 or T3 etc. I would also like it to sum the B's and T's where a cell contains values like B2T3

So example:

```
B5
B5
B2T3
T3
```

Should show me B = 12 and T = 6

In the attached screenshot, I cannot get the formulat to recognise and pickup the B and T values from cell F2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+TEXT(LEFT(TEXT(MID($A$2:$A$5&"@",FIND(C2,$A$2:$A$5&C2)+1,COLUMN(A:I)),),COLUMN(A:I)-1),"[<>];;;\0"))
```

[image]

**Edit :**

If the data put in horizontally, just change this formula part from **COLUMN(A:I)** to **ROW($1:$9)**

It is a robust formula, criteria & data can be variable, and sum with decimal point numbers

In A2, formula copied right to B2 and all copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+TEXT(LEFT(TEXT(MID($C2:$F2&"@",FIND(A$1,$C2:$F2&A$1)+1,ROW($1:$9)),),ROW($1:$9)-1),"[<>];;;\0"))
```

[image]

Comment: Works for sum of coloumns. What would be the change to make it work for sum of rows?

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If `T` would alway comes after `B`, you may try the following CSE-entered formula:

To get `T`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--MID(C2:F2,FIND("T",C2:F2)+1,LEN(C2:F2)),0))
```

To get `B`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--MID(C2:F2,FIND("B",C2:F2)+1,IFERROR(FIND("T",C2:F2)-2,100)),0))
```

[image]

Drag to `B2`.

---

Surely, someone can come up with something cleaner =)

Comment: I couldn't think of one. I did try using filterxml as an exercise using your excellent tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml as a reference and it is possible, but fairly long that way.

Comment: Yeah I tried the same thing but it figured that OP probably got more cells than just the four so I stuck to what I had. Still feels like Im missing something. Even tried `IMSUM()`. @TomSharpe... I just can't do without O365 myself nomore if I see all this hassle =)